# app static to dynamic error. Sentry nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, sentry

I'm encountering a 500 error when attempting to compile a Next.js frontend on a Kubernetes pod. I'm using the following commands:

```
npm i --force
npm run build
npm run start
```

this is the error:

```
Page changed from static to dynamic at runtime /story/0d3778b0-9e86-4b0a-a043-ed892f2417a0, reason: headers                                                                                              see more here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-static-to-dynamic-error                                                                                                                                   at Object.staticGenerationBailout (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:26985:21)                                                                                                                            at headers (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:26854:39)                                                                                                                                                   at Object.apply (/app/.next/server/chunks/500.js:78:82)                                                                                                                                                  at T (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:27630:25)                                                                                                                                                          at Ma (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:27793:33)                                                                                                                                                       at Array.toJSON (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:27586:32)                                                                                                                                             at stringify (<anonymous>)                                                                                                                                                                             at V (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:27885:53)                                                                                                                                                        at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:341:14)                                                                                                                                                       at Object.start (/app/.next/server/chunks/827.js:27997:32)
```

I suspect that the issue may be related to my Sentry configuration, as the front-end works fine when I don't use Sentry. Here is the code for my Sentry configuration in the page/_error.js file:

import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import NextErrorComponent from 'next/error';

const SENTRY_DSN = process.env.NEXT_SENTRY_DSN || process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN;
const isSentryEnabled = !!SENTRY_DSN;

```
if (isSentryEnabled) {
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: SENTRY_DSN,
  });
}

const CustomErrorComponent = ({ statusCode, hasGetInitialPropsRun, err }) => {
  if (isSentryEnabled) {
    Sentry.captureException(err);

    if (!hasGetInitialPropsRun && err) {
      Sentry.captureException(err);
      return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={500} />;
    }

    // Render the default Next.js error page with the status code
    return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={statusCode} />;
  }

  // Render the default Next.js error page with the status code
  return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={statusCode} />;
};

CustomErrorComponent.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  if (isSentryEnabled) {
    if (context.err) {
      Sentry.captureException(context.err);
    }

    const { res, err, asPath } = context;

    if (res && res.statusCode === 404) {
      return { statusCode: 404 };
    }

    const hasGetInitialPropsRun = Boolean(err);
    if (err) {
      Sentry.captureException(err);
    }

    const initialProps = await NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps(context);
    return { ...initialProps, hasGetInitialPropsRun, err, asPath };
  } else {
    const initialProps = await NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps(context);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }
};

export default CustomErrorComponent;
```

I changed the configuration to a default sentry nextjs

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";
import NextErrorComponent from "next/error";

const CustomErrorComponent = props => {
  Sentry.captureException(props.err); // Capture the error in Sentry
  return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={props.statusCode} />;
};

CustomErrorComponent.getInitialProps = async contextData => {
  Sentry.captureException(contextData.err); // Capture the error in Sentry
  return {
    statusCode: contextData.res?.statusCode ?? 500,
    // Set the following to null to disable "Static Generation" optimization
    // for this page
    getStaticProps: null,
    getStaticPaths: null,
  };
};

export default CustomErrorComponent;
```

and attempting to prevent the rendering of the Sentry _error.js file when I run the build process.

```
npm run build
```

I already tried change the versions of nextJs

Some of my dependencies are:

```
- next-auth@4.20.1
- next@13.1.6
- @next/font@13.1.6
- @sentry/nextjs@7.43.0
- @next-auth/sequelize-adapter@1.0.7
- @next-auth/typeorm-legacy-adapter@2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a Next.js problem. Check out [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45068#issuecomment-1401196895) where they claim that the issue has been fixed in `v13.1.6-canary.0`. Some people claim that reverting back to version `3.1.1` fixed the issue. Try upgrading/downgrading the version and see if the issue still persists.